# Java: How to generate a random number bigger than x, no maximum?

Tags: java, math, random

I just want to generate a random number bigger than x, without a maximum value, to operate with it afterwards. I've been searching for answers to my question but none of them match my problem: they refer to a restriction with minimum and maximum values. I want a simple code just like:

```
Random number = new Random();
int x = 0; //the minimum value
int finalNumber;//any positive random number, in this case; if, for example, x were 2, some number bigger than 2.
```

How can I get finalNumber?

Thanks for taking your time in posting an answer, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Since `finalNumber` is an `int` there is an inherent maximum number which is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2,147,483,647).

Comment: A random number between x and infinity would have to be on average halfway to infinity which is infinity. In fact you have the probability of 0 to get a number that's not infinity with those bounds.

Comment: Considering how many numbers there are above 2, you would with 99.999999....% certainty get a number that is larger than the number of atoms in the universe ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since information is stored into finite bytes you can't in any case generate a number with "no maximum".

So assuming your limit it `Integer.MAX_VALUE` then you can generate a number in `[0, Integer.MAX_VALUE - minimum]` and then add minimum to the result.

Eg:

```
final int MINIMUM = ...
int v = random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE - MINIMUM) + MINIMUM;
```

Mind that this is exclusive since `nextInt(int)` contract specify that upper bound is excluded. And that this required `MINIMUM` to be positive.

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that this works because MINIMUM is positive - otherwise you risk an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wrap it with your own class/utility method say MyMath.Random() like this method:

```
public class MyMath{
   public static int Random()
   {
      final int MIN = 0;
      final int MAX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      return (int)(Math.random() * MAX);
   }
   /// overload so you can specify min value
   public static int Random(in MIN)
   {
      final int MAX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      return (int)(Math.random() * (MAX-MIN));
   }
}
```

You can refer to the Integer.MAX_VALUE from the Java docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

This way you can just do:

`int someInt = MyMath.Random();`

or

`int x = 123;
int someInt = MyMath.Random(x);`

Comment: If MIN is an int and MAX is Integer.MAX_VALUE than there is no physical way MIN <= MAX can return false. Also, use the constant instead of copying it's value and mentioning in a comment where you got it from.

Comment: Thanks @Deltharis, it's just that I was in the direction of having code of being able to specify a max value other than the Integer constant. But to be aligned with the question, I've updated my answer to use the Integer constant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`if (x > 0) {
    return (int)(Math.random() * (Integer.MAX_VALUE - x)) + x;
}`